# How add page for pagination in protocol oriented networking

Tags: swift, networking, protocols

I just learn how to create a protocol oriented networking, but I just don't get how to add page for pagination in protocol. my setup is like this

```
protocol Endpoint {
    var base: String { get }
    var path: String { get }
}

extension Endpoint {
    var apiKey: String {
        return "api_key=SOME_API_KEY"
    }
    
    var urlComponents: URLComponents {
        var components = URLComponents(string: base)!
        components.path = path
        components.query = apiKey
        return components
    }
    
    var request: URLRequest {
        let url = urlComponents.url!
        return URLRequest(url: url)
    }
}

enum MovieDBResource {
    case popular
    case topRated
    case nowPlaying
    case reviews(id: Int)
}

extension MovieDBResource: Endpoint {
    var base: String {
        return "https://api.themoviedb.org"
    }
    
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .popular: return "/3/movie/popular"
        case .topRated: return "/3/movie/top_rated"
        case .nowPlaying: return "/3/movie/now_playing"
        case .reviews(let id): return "/3/movie/\(id)/videos"
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my network service class method

```
func getReview(movie resource: MovieDBResource, completion: @escaping (Result<MovieItem, MDBError>) -> Void) {
        print(resource.request)
        fetch(with: resource.request, decode: { (json) -> MovieItem? in
            guard let movieResults = json as? MovieItem else { return nil }
            return movieResults
        }, completion: completion)
    }
```

How I add page in protocol so I can called and add parameter in viewController, for now my service in my viewController is like this. I need parameter to page

```
service.getReview(movie: .reviews(id: movie.id)) { [weak self] results in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch results {
            case .success(let movies):
                print(movies)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it as a parameter to your enum case like:
`case popular(queryParameters: [String: Any])`

You can create `Router` class that has `buildRequest(_:Endpoint)`, and here you can get the `queryParameters` and add it to the url witch will contain `page` and `limit` or any other query parameters.

you can also add another parameter for `bodyParameters` if the request HTTPMethod is `POST` and you need to send data in the body.

Comment: I see what you suggest, but I still don't get how I can use buildRequest in the router. I'm sorry I'm still new in this

Comment: `buildRequest` is your custom method that takes `Endpoint` as a parameter and already your `endpoint` has the `request` and `URL`, so all you need to do is to check if you have `queryParameters`, you will parse these items to the request url.

so you now will have the request with url and already added the query parameters to it.

Comment: check this article will help you 
https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/writing-network-layer-in-swift-protocol-oriented-approach-4fa40ef1f908